# cygwin compile C source with Gcc and set include in different place

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

hi i want compile in cygwin a C source, but i want include also library,the library is placed in another location then prog but i dont know why it not want recongnize that.
I used  this code:

```
gcc -c -fpic -O2 stringregexp.c  -I /../../language/include   
or
 gcc -c -fpic -O2 stringregexp.c  -I /cygdrive/c/ring/language/include
```

error
ring.h:106:18: fatal error: ring_ext.h: No such file or directory
106 |         #include "ring_ext.h"

thanks

Comment: You forgot to include the full unedited text of the error message.

Comment: sorry  ring.h:106:18: fatal error: ring_ext.h: No such file or directory
  106 |         #include "ring_ext.h"

Comment: Is there a file named ring_ext.h in /cygdrive/c/ring/language/include ? If not, is there such file anywhere in any subdirectory? In which one?

Comment: `ring_ext.h` belongs to the `Ring Compiler` https://ring-lang.github.io/doc1.7/extension.html . Have someone built it for Cygwin for you to use ?

Comment: I  have always placed the `-I dir` option before the source file that needs it.

Comment: `-I /../../language/include` is clearly wrong as `/` is the root and there is no parent `..`. As you are compiling something very specific, please provide all the steps you did and the full error with the command that caused it.